# Creating a function that assigns a random index location a specific number

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, python-3.4

So I'm working on a card game project in Python, and I've been given some starter code to work with. We have a function called `assignCard`, which is supposed to assign an index location in an array of 52 "cards" to the deck, the player, or the computer.

Here is the code:

```
""" cardGame.py
basic card game framework
keeps track of card locations for as many hands as needed
"""
NUMCARDS = 52
DECK = 0
PLAYER = 1
COMP = 2

cardLoc = [0] * NUMCARDS
suitName = ("hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs")
rankName = ("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", 
        "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King")
playerName = ("deck", "player", "computer")

def main():
    clearDeck()

    for i in range(5):
       assignCard(PLAYER)
       assignCard(COMP)

    showDeck()
    showHand(PLAYER)
    showHand(COMP)

def clearDeck():
    cardLoc[0] * NUMCARDS

def assignCard(playerName):

def showDeck():
    print("#        card                location")

def showHand(playerName):

main()
```

We aren't supposed to edit anything above the end of the main function, the only thing we are writing are the functions inside the main function.

We are dealing five cards to each player, so my question is, using the `for i in range(5)` to deal five cards, how can I exclusively deal five cards to each player? I'm having a bit of trouble associating arrays and indices, so any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

generate an array of numbers from 0 to 51, map every number to a card. shuffle the array. in every turn, give player the first card in the array and remove it.